# Cómo desbloquear conexión de mysql?

Tags: mysql

He hecho muchas peticiones a una base de datos mysql y me ha bloqueado la ip desde la que la hago, porque he hecho muchas conexiones con errores.

He probado con entrando con el administrador y ejecutando

```
mysqladmin flush-hosts;
```

Pero no me desbloquea esa ip, me vuelve a sacar el mismo error.

```
"Host '...' is blocked because of many connection errors; 
 unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'
```

No sé si esta mal mi sintaxis o estoy haciendo algo mal, muchas gracias.

Comment: has hecho lo que te indica? El mysqladmin flush-hosts

Comment: mysql> flush hosts;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Comment: y despues de hacerlo sigue sin dejarte conectar?

Comment: Si, lo raro es que me ejecuta sin errores pero luego no me conecta, no he probado a reiniciar el servicio de mysql, pero quiero asegurarme que si lo hago funciona.

Comment: Intenta reiniciar el servicio del MySql despues de haber hecho la consulta. Esto suele resolver ese problema.

Answer (score 1):

si `flush-host` no te funciona correctamente, podrías probar a aumentar el numero maximo de errores por ip:

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL max_connect_errors = 100000000;
```

Answer (score 0):

No has mencionado si revisaste el firewall del equipo y si puedes acceder desde esa Ip usando otro metodo.

El problema podria deberse a que fue el firewall quien te bloqueo. Para escuchar todas las conexiones remotas verifica el archivo /etc/mysql/my.cnf especificamente la seccion de bind-address:

bind-address = xx.xxx.xx.xx

Configuralo para que escuche todo:

bind-address = 0.0.0.0